# Node.js App Fails to Connect to PostgreSQL in Docker Container Due to Timing Issue?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've following problem
I'm creating a simple app with Node.js and postgresql

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

and i hit
`docker build -t my-app .`

It just works fine

after that I type `docker compose up`

with follwing docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password123
      POSTGRES_USER: user123
      POSTGRES_DB: db123
  app:
    image: my-app
    ports:
      - 3333:3000
```

docker print
`database system is ready to accept connections`

but node.js coudn't connect database

I checked what docker container is running
with this command `docker ps`

only postgres is running and my-app status is Exited (because It coudn't connect DB)

after that i kill docker using `ctrl + c`

and `docker compose up` again

my-app and postgres both are running well.

I think there is timing issue with my docker

If I added `restart: always`` option in app service it works fine

```
  app:
    restart: always
    image: my-app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

But seems like not a good solution I think ...

any other solutions ?
what am I missing something?

1.add restart:always option in app service => it works
2.add depends-on options but => no work

Comment: You can probably use `depends_on` with a healthcheck on the database see [depends_on long syntax in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#depends_on)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably, in my opinion, use the wrong host to connect your `express.js` service to `Postgres`.

Docker-Compose:

```java
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres_service:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: db_name
```

Host to connect `express.js` service to `postgres` db should be **postgres_service**.

Example:

```js
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: "postgres_service",
  port: 5432,
  username: "user",
  password: "pass",
  database: "db_name",
  migrations: [],
  entities: [],
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: true,
});
```

Comment: it's my db source,
no work. 
```
const pool = new Pool({
  host: 'db',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db_name',
});
```

Comment: @Cono Also another reason why your service not connect just that you `app` service not waiting before `postgres` service app and run the same time like `postgres`.

You can try to add `depends_on` in you `docker-compose` file where `app` service. App service will run after `postgres` service.